# First time using an API in JS; need some array and page load guidance

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

I am in a nine month bootcamp program and am somewhat stuck on one of our sprint projects. I'm using the jService API to make a jeopardy game.

1. I don't know how to get my question/answer to populate in the table, especially in a column that corresponds to the ID of the category. Where should I look; can someone provide an example?
2. When I open this with liveserver, I have to call getCategory(catId) and fillTable(categories) in the console to populate the table. Why? What am I doing wrong?

The comments are the directions for this project; I've removed the directions from the other functions as I completed them.

I am very beginner so please excuse this mess, and I really appreciate and am thankful for any resources, direction, or examples:

```
let categories = [];
let catId = [];
let clueArray = [];
let clue = [];
let title, response, question, answer, text, newTh, NUM_CATEGORIES, target;

async function getCategoryIds() {
    const response = await axios.get('http://jservice.io/api/categories?count=10');
    NUM_CATEGORIES = _.sampleSize(response.data, [n = 6]);

    for (let num of NUM_CATEGORIES) {
        let categoryID = num.id;
        catId.push(categoryID); 
    }
    return catId;
}
getCategoryIds();

function getCategory(catId){
    catId.forEach(async function (ID) {
        response = await axios.get('http://jservice.io/api/clues?category=' + ID);

        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            question = response.data[i].question;
            answer = response.data[i].answer;
            title = response.data[i].category.title;

            clueArray = _.sampleSize(clueArray, [n = 5]);
            clueArray.push({ question, answer });
        }

        clue = {
            title: title,
            clueArray: clueArray,
            showing: null
        }
        categories.push(clue);
    })   
    return categories;
}
getCategory(catId);

function fillTable(categories) {
    for (let cat of categories) {
        let newTh = document.createElement("TH");
        let text = document.createTextNode(cat.title);
        newTh.appendChild(text);
        document.querySelector("thead").appendChild(newTh);

        let newTr = document.createElement("TR");
        document.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(newTr);

        clueArray.forEach(function (cat) {
            let newTd = document.createElement("TD");
            newTd.innerText = "?";
            newTd.id = 'td';
            // newTd.bind('click', handleClick);
            newTr.appendChild(newTd);
        })
    }
}
fillTable(categories);

/** Handle clicking on a clue: show the question or answer.
 *
 * Uses .showing property on clue to determine what to show:
 * - if currently null, show question & set .showing to "question"
 * - if currently "question", show answer & set .showing to "answer"
 * - if currently "answer", ignore click
 * */

$(document.tbody).on('click', '.tbody *', function (e) {
    for (let cat of categories) {
        target = e.currentTarget;
        if (target = '#td') {
            for (let cat of categories) {
                target.innerHTML = cat.clueArray[i].question;
            }
        }
    }
});




/** Start game:
 *
 * - get random category Ids
 * - get data for each category
 * - create HTML table
 * */

function setupAndStart() {
 }

/** On click of restart button, restart game. */
restart.addEventListener('click', function () {
    location.reload();
})


// /** On page load, setup and start & add event handler for clicking clues */
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Ready!");
});
```

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for at all, here’s my general remark: I would try to make the code declarative (express what you are doing, instead of how you’re doing it - you can research declarative vs imperative code on the web); if I were you, I’d try using a frontend framework like ReactJS, VueJS or Angular (personal preference on ReactJS, although I haven’t tested VueJS). Modern enterprise app seldomly go the pure vanilla JS or jquery way, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has to be called in order because one function relies on the next: `getCategoryIds -> getCategory -> fillTable` but there is currently not enough time for the previous function to finish before  the next one starts.

If you ignore the function declarations your code is executed in this order almost instantly:

```js
getCategoryIds(); 
getCategory(catId); // getCategoryIds is not finished yet!
fillTable(categories) // getCategoryIds and getCategory aren't finished yet so there is nothing to add to the table;
```

When you are calling the functions in the console you are giving the previous function enough time to finish.

I see that you're using async/await so here's a quick solution using that:

```js
// declare a new async function 
async function initialize() {
  await getCategoryIds() // wait for this async function to finish
  await Promise.all(getCategory(catId)) // getCategory(catId) returns an array of promises so we can wait for all of these to finish using Promise.all
  fillTable(categories); 
}

initialize() // call this function instead of all the functions individually
```

This should be enough to get you unstuck. :)

For further reading the [YDKJS series](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/1st-ed) is great. It's best read in order but the [Async & Performance](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/async%20&%20performance/README.md#you-dont-know-js-async--performance) book would help you understand the async nature of js.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate the insight and the explanation explaining it!